# RSpec: where in the directory structure should I place an integration test covering multiple classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I made an integration test in RSpec that uses several classes. Some of them are models; Other classes are non-model, the kind that reside under `lib`.

The test is not driven by get/post calls (Otherwise I would've made it a feature test or a request test). It encompasses a back-end process, typically triggered by a Sidekiq worker or an evet that happens in the system for that matter.

What would be the proper directory under the RSpec directory tree to place this spec?

Answer (score 1):

You could create special a directory, just for integration specs *(called integration_tests for example)*. It will break `RSpec` ability to infer spec type from location, though.

As a second option, you can write integration tests at the highest level of abstraction. So it won't have a special place and some integration tests will be in `models`, some in `controllers`, others in `lib`. As a drawback your integration tests will naturally clatter with unit tests.

I've seen both options. Second is more common in bigger projects, where the former one is mostly used in small projects and gems